# Как всегда узнавать, кто присоединился к голосовому чату discord py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

как выполнить действие, если кто-то присоединился к голосовому чату и узнать его имя?

Answer (score 2):

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_voice_state_update(self, before: discord.Message, after: discord.Message):
    if after.channel and before.channel == None:
        # зашел в войс
        print(str(message.author))

    elif before.channel and after.channel == None:
        # вышел из войса
        pass

    elif before.channel and after.channel:
        # изменения внутри войса
        pass
        
        if before.self_mute != after.self_mute:
            # включил или выключил микро
            pass

        elif before.self_deaf != after.self_deaf:
            # включил или выключил звук
            pass

        elif after.self_stream:
            if before.self_stream == False:
                # включил стрим
                pass
        else:
            # перешел из 1 войса в другой
```